# Linux - Serial port behaviour different from socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, nonblocking

I've opened */dev/ttyACM0* in non-blocking mode mode.

I am using *select* to know when data is available.

When *select* returns, I can read all the data that has arrived by the serial port with the *read* function.

The problem is that if I try to read MORE data, *read* returns **0**.

This is NOT the proper behaviour.

Explanation:

When opening a socket in *non-blocking mode*, *select* returns when data is available and the *read* function can be called to retrieve the data.

However, calling *read* on a socket that has NO DATA to read will cause *read* to return **-1**, NOT **0**.

The associated *errno* is *EWOULDBLOCK*, which is correct.

In the case of the serial port descriptor, everything is the same except *read* returns **0** when there is no data and *errno* is also **0**.

For a socket, *read* returning **0** signifies that the remote has closed their end of the session and this should be the moment where you close the local side of your connection.

As it is, the serial-port *read* returns **0**, but the port has **not** been closed.

Is there a way to initialize the comm port so it behaves identically to a socket?

Thanks

Comment: I don't disagree with any of your observations, but where do you get the claim that the observed behavior is improper?  Serial ports are not sockets, and they are not documented to behave identically.  As far as this hypothetical API that changes a serial port to be 100% identical to a socket, no, there isn't.  Nothing you do to a serial port will make it work with socket APIs (`shutdown`, `bind`, `recvmsg`).  Nor will socket code know what to do with baud rates and parity errors.  Perhaps you would be happier using a real socket, connected to a serial port proxy/wrapper?

Comment: I'd settle for a way to understand what is going on: read returning 0 can't be distinguished from /dev/ttyACM0 being removed from the system or there simply being no data available. That is the basic thing I'd like to resolve, how to tell the difference between no data and no hardware

Comment: Hmm, on Windows I use Device Manager notifications to detect device removal, rather than API error codes.  On Linux the near equivalent is the hotplug system...  But you should be able to use API calls for this.

Comment: Still, I'm surprised that the "hardware removed" case gives you a return value of `0`.  It should fail with either *EPIPE* or something analogous.

Comment: It's because the man page I am referring to says this:

Comment: "On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file), [...] On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately. [...]"

Comment: "Errors:
EAGAIN
The file descriptor fd refers to a file other than a socket and has been marked nonblocking (O_NONBLOCK), and the read would block.
EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK
The file descriptor fd refers to a socket and has been marked nonblocking (O_NONBLOCK), and the read would block. POSIX.1-2001 allows either error to be returned for this case, and does not require these constants to have the same value, so a portable application should check for both possibilities."

Comment: As you've noted, Ben, it does seem strange that there is no error code for the removal of the hardware

Comment: More detail; on hardware removal, select returns a value greater than 0, indicating there is an event to process, so there is no indication of anything other than a read-event. Calling read to see if there is data returns 0 and sets errno to 0 also. This is exactly the SAME behaviour as when there IS data to read: select returns a value greater than 0, read then returns a value greater than 0 until a final read, which returns 0 and sets errno to 0 also instead of EWOULDBLOCK. That's the heart of the problem; why doesn't errno ever get set to EWOULDBLOCK, like it says it should in the doc?

Comment: Whose doc are you looking at?  `read()` is a pretty straight-forward kernel call, and in the kernel it's a virtual dispatch (built using function pointers because Linus doesn't allow C++... ).   The common code is only the argument-checking (*EBADF* or *EPOINTER* or *EACCESS*).  So how the developer of the kernel module for that particular serial port implemented the `read()` override determines the behavior with that model serial adapter.  Some of them might be buggy, especially if the developer didn't use non-blocking mode himself.

Comment: Another thing to try would be testing with `poll()`, which distinguishes more events than `select()` does.

Comment: `... The problem is that if I try to read MORE data, read returns 0. ...` If select() tells you the fd is readable, you are allowed to call read() on that fd **once**. After that: set up the fd_sets again, and call select() again. [ALSO: add some **code** to your question]

Comment: Ben - this is the doc https://linux.die.net/man/2/read most documentations of read state the possibility of EWOULDBLOCK

Comment: wildplasser - You're correct in stating that read can only be reliably expected to return data for the FIRST read but it is common to loop upon receipt of a read-event until an EWOULDBLOCK occurs. A holdover from my Windows programming days, probably, there, a recv would return -1 and WSAGetLastError would return WSA_EWOULDBLOCK

Comment: Of course, in Windows, there was no posix-everything-is-a-socket, especially for serial ports.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a way to distinguish device removal (either unplug a serial port from the parent bus, e.g. USB, or forcible driver unload) from no data, call an API whose outcome doesn't depend on the receive buffer.

For example, `tcgetattr` should succeed whether or not there is data, as long as the device still exists.

If you want to detect disconnection of a serial cable, you either need hardware handshaking, or a timeout.